# Will 32-bit version of GhostScript work on 64-bit systems?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, ghostscript

I'm going to redistribute gsdll32.dll, main library of GhostScript. There are two versions available for download, 32 and 64 bit. Will the first one work on 64-bit systems, or I need package two versions separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the .exe is built.  If you build a .exe for 32 bit, you need the 32 bit dll.  It will work on 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: OK, so if I choose to compile for 32 bit, it will work fine in compatibility mode, right?

Comment: It just works.  64 bit machines come with plenty of 32 bit software installed.  You just have to make sure that everything is compiled the same way.